# Jquery unobtrusive how to

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, validation

i am dynamically loading partial view in view via that code:

```
$("#typeOfQuestion").load("/Form/TechnicalQuestionPartial");
    $(".questionType").click(function () {
        var UrlPass;
        if ($(this).val() === "techinicalQuestion") {
            UrlPass = "/Form/TechnicalQuestionPartial";
            //            $('#typeOfQuestion').load("/Form/TechnicalQuestionPartial");
        } else if ($(this).val() === "suggestion") {
            UrlPass = "/Form/SuggestionPartial";
            //            $('#typeOfQuestion').load("/Form/Suggestion");
        }
        $.ajax({
            url: UrlPass,
            success: function (data) {
                $('#typeOfQuestion').html(data);
                $('#typeOfQuestion').html($("#formTrim").html());
                validateAjaxForm();
            }
        });
    });
```

The problem is that the partial view is loaded in html.beginform and some properties of  the partial view need to be validated
I am using jquery unobtrusive for validation but it doesnt work i need a tutorial to see how exactly it is done

Answer (score 0):

You need to parse the newly added element in order to register them with the validation using the `$.validator.unobtrusive.parse` method:

```
success: function (data) {
    $('#typeOfQuestion').html(data);
    $('#typeOfQuestion').html($("#formTrim").html());

    // reparse the form DOM in order to register unobtrusive validation
    // to newly added elements
    $("form").removeData("validator");
    $("form").removeData("unobtrusiveValidation");
    $.validator.unobtrusive.parse("form");
}
```

Comment: i already tried that and i am  still not able to get the validation out, what else can i try

Comment: That's how unobtrusive validation works. If this doesn't work for you I guess you are doing something wrong. Hard to tell without showing your full code allowing us to reproduce the problem.